# How to prevent my site from loading in iframe using php

Tags: php, html, http

I tried to block the site load in another location but my attempts did not succeed even after using.

```
<?php
header(X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com);
header(X-Frame-Options: deny);
?>
```

Is there another solution? Makes downloading your site from any place prohibited except my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php header("X-Frame-Options: sameorigin");?>
```

It prevents your site from loading in any site to your site itself
See this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options